# Laravel can't find controller, but will report any syntax errors in said controller if they exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

just trying to get to grips with the basics of Laravel. I was getting syntax errors in my areasController file. Once they were resolved I started recieving this error: ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\areasController does not exist. So it seems like Laravel can find the file to know that when there are errors in it, but not the rest of the time. Any help appreciated, this is my first framework so I'm pretty stumped.

routes.php:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('locations', function() {
    return view('locations');
});

Route::get('areas', '   areasController@areas');
```

areasController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

class areas extends Controller
{
    //
    public function areas() {

        $areas = DB::table('areas')->all();

        return view('areas');   

    }

}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Reporting syntax errors is a job of a php's interpreter, but laravel cannot find your controller not because he doesn't know where the file is, but he doesn't find the class name. It should be `areasController`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes.php` file, you ask to use the method `areas` from `areasController` but in your controller file, you define `class areas extends Controller`

It should be `class areasController extends Controller` then it should work